# Как менять цвет placeholder-a через javascript?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, dom

Всем привет! У меня есть инпут, как я могу поменять цвет placeholder-a при на фокусе на input? Сделать примерно как при входе ВКонтакте. То есть, если есть наведение на инпут, placeholder становится более прозрачным, ну или цвет более можно сделать ярким.

```
<input type="text" class="login" placeholder="Телефон или email">
```

Узнал что можно вот так прописать в стилях:

```
.login::placeholder {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Но тут у меня проблемы: Я всегда решал задачки через classList.add, заранее прописывая класс со стилями в файле style.css, где хранились все мои стили. Добвавлялось все просто, типо add('active') и т.д. Но сейчас возникла проблема, не знаю как работать в javascript-e c псевдо-классами. Есть ли какое-то решение? Кто сталкивался?

Comment: изменять псевдоэлементы через javascript неполучиться

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/shadow-dom

Comment: @soledar10: правда не получится? А `after` и `before` тоже?

Comment: Ну так добавьте стиль `.login.active::placeholder { ... }` — он и будет появляться через `classList.add('active')` )

Comment: @UModeL  да и к after и before также нет доступа

Comment: @soledar10: что я сделал не так? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/959767/265406

Comment: @UModeL  - ваше решение использует css cв-во, речь идет о прямом доступе к псевдоэлементу(ам)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.login::placeholder {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.login:focus::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  color: red;
}

.login:hover::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="login" placeholder="Телефон или email">
```

---

Из JS с помощью CSS-переменных тоже можно добраться:

```js
function fColorPlaceholder(val) {
  document.querySelector('.login').style.setProperty(`--placeholder`, `hsl(${120 + val * 3},100%,50%)`);
}
```

```css
body { text-align: center; }

.login { --placeholder: 50;}
.login::placeholder { color: var(--placeholder, grey); }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="login" placeholder="Телефон или email">
<br>
<input type="range" oninput="fColorPlaceholder(this.value)">
```

Comment: Благодарочка, работает. Только все же думал через javascript. Хотя по вашему мнению такие вещи все же делать через css?

Comment: @МирасТекесбаев: добавил пример. По аналогии можно изменять почти все свойства. Чисто в декоративных целях, лучше CSS (сейчас появилось много плюшек всяких).